# How to get element inside other specific element using its id and getElementById?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, web

I'm writing a really big script and performance is a big deal for me, especially that it has to work as fast as it can in IE (employer requirements). I have to do some `innerHTML` and stuff like that but for an element that has some class or id and is nested into some other element with some id or class.

I can do it using `querySelector()`, but as I saw in some performance tests for IE, `querySelector` is a few times slower than `getElementById` or even `getElementsByClassName()`. That's why I want to use these `getElement...` functions.

Here's an example:

```
<div id='firstID' class='someClass'>
  <div id='secondID' class='someClass2'></div>
</div>
<div id='thirdID' class='someClass'>
  <div id='secondID' class='someClass2'></div>
</div>
```

And I want to get this `secondID` element but it has to be one in `firstID` element. Like I said before, I can use `querySelector('#firstID #secondID')`; or a jQuery equivalent but it is much slower than `getElementById()` so I'm asking you how can I translate it into `getElementById`?

P.S. In my tests `getElementById` was performed `1 300 000` times per second whereas `querySelector` was perfomed about `400 000` times. So, you see where I'm getting with that.

Comment: Ids are supposed to be singular to a page.

Comment: In your case I would do `getElementById("firstID").firstElementChild`, and as commented, you can't use same id twice and expect that to work.

Comment: Of course, but, unfortunately, categories I'm generating dynamically, may be same in other parent categories, so I kind of need to create some identical ids on different elements.

Comment: So then make the ID of the element a combination of the parent name and item name. You're making it far harder for yourself.

Comment: [W3 specification for the `id` attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/2012/WD-html5-20121025/global-attributes.html#the-id-attribute): "The value must be unique…" @krillgar's suggestion to prefix the nested IDs with the parent ID is best and will give you the ability to directly select an element with `getElementById` which will be the most performant as well. Example: `<div id='firstID-secondID'…>`

Comment: Ok, thanks Guys. I'll try it out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never ever use the same ID twice ( ID stand for identity and two elements can't have the same identity ). You can use the class name instead

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="a">
            <div id="b" class="someClass2"></div>
        </div>
        <div id="c">
            <div id="d" class="someClass2"></div>
        </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        var parent = document.getElementById("a");
        var childs = parent.getElementsByClassName("someClass2");
        var firstSomeClass2Element = childs[0];
        firstSomeClass2Element.innerHTML = "Example";
    </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

More about ID:

> The Element.id property represents the element's identifier,
>   reflecting the id global attribute.
>
> It must be unique in a document, and is often used to retrieve the
>   element using getElementById. Other common usages of id include using
>   the element's ID as a selector when styling the document with CSS.

https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Element/id

Here is the solution you need but is very very bad

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="a">
            <div id="b" class="someClass2">a</div>
        </div>
        <div id="c">
            <div id="b" class="someClass2">s</div>
        </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        var parent = document.getElementById("a");
        var childs = parent.childNodes;

        for (var i = 0; i < childs.length; i++) {
            if (childs[i].nodeType == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
                if(childs[i].id == "b") {
                    console.log("Done");
                }
            }
        }
    </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

**Example with attached function**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="a">
            <div id="b" class="someClass2">a</div>
        </div>
        <div id="c">
            <div id="b" class="someClass2">s</div>
        </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        HTMLElement.prototype.findId = function(_id) {
            var childs = this.childNodes;

            for (var i = 0; i < childs.length; i++) {
                if(childs[i].nodeType == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
                    if(childs[i].id == _id) {
                        return childs[i];
                    }
                }
            }

            return null;
        }

        // Usage Example
        var parent = document.getElementById("a");
        console.dir(parent.findId("b"));

    </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Ok, I know. But these names in my script are generated dynamically based on list items from Sharepoint list (using SPServices). And unfortunately few items have identical names but different parents, so I need to create it like this.

Comment: You can still use the example i gave you. Just take advantage of the element class name

Comment: Ok, I'll try it out. Thanks. :)

Comment: Check the edit. I wrote another example. Note: I don't recommend it.

Comment: Thanks for it, but my script is builded in way that disallows me to implement it, I will try to combine parent name into id of an secondID element though.

Comment: Another Alternative answer :D

Comment: Thanks, guys! I combined parentID with child ID what makes them individual and so it makes my problem dissapear! :)